# Changing permissions for folders and files in /var/www/?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, webserver, cms

I am quite new to ubuntu and I have been trying to install BuilderEngine, a content management system, to my ubuntu server 12.04 lts. I have figured some things out but I am struggling with permission for files and folders.
I know I have to change the permission for folders and files in /var/www/ to be able to read and write files. But I am not sure what to do.

All I know is never use `chmod -R 777 /var/www/` because that can read/write/excute files.

Was thinking of trying `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/` but not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the group is www-data on '/var/www'

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www
```

Make '/var/www' writable for the group

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

Set the GID for www-data for all sub-folders

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Your directory should look like this on an `ls -l` output.

> drwxrwsr-x

Last, add your username to the www-data group (secondary group)

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data [YOURUSERNAME]
```

Comment: Does this method work with ubuntu server 12.04 LTS because I only found out that it is easier to install the Builderengine cms on 12.04 version. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Yes, this should work with ubuntu server 12.04.

Comment: Was able to to get into 192.168.0.xx/admin/install/index but sadly my last check box for the installation progess was unchecked it was : website folder is not writable

Comment: doesn't matter fixed it

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The last terminal command you reference returns an error: `useradd: user '[myusername]' already exists`, and I still can't write to /var/www/ to start working on websites

Comment: The right final command is - `sudo usermod -a -G GROUP USER` where GROUP is the desired existing group and USER is the desired existing user

Comment: Also, if you already have files inside /var/www then the change /var/www AT THE CMD to `/var/www/* -R` so for example `sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/* -R`

Answer (score 3):

My Suggestion for the permission you can use below command to find and set p:

```
find /var/www/html/ -type d -perm 777 |xargs chmod 0755 --
find /var/www/html/ -type f -perm 777 |xargs chmod 0644 --
```

OR

For Directories:

```
 find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

For Files:

```
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```